# Realm database in production

Tags: deployment, realm, cloud, icloud

I developed an application using Realm database with user authentication via iCloud token.

Now I want to publish my application to the App Store and need to deploy Realm to the production.

My question is: What is the best and easiest way to deploy my Realm DB? I tried Realm Cloud and Azure with preinstalled image, but neither of those supported configuration of the Realm to communicate with iCloud. And all resources I found linked to non-existing Realm docs.